# Prove that every topological space equipped with the discrete topology is zero-dimensional.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

> Prove that every topological space equipped with the discrete topology is zero-dimensional.

Let $X$ be a topological space and $\tau = \mathcal{P}(X)$. Now in order to show that the collection $\mathcal{B}=\{\{x\} : x \in X\}$ forms a basis for $X$ we need to show that it covers $X$ and that for $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$ where $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$ we can find $B \in \mathcal{B} $ such that $x \in B \subset B_1 \cap B_2 $.

Now the first condition is true since $X \subseteq \bigcup_{B \in \mathcal{B}} B = \bigcup_{x \in X} \{x\}.$

For the second condition let $B_1, B_2 \in \mathcal{B}$ and let $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$. The only way this can be true is that $B_1=B_2=\{x\}$ so the $B = B_1 \cap B_2 = \{x\}$?

Now we’re still left to show that the elements of the basis are closed in order to show that $X$ is zero-dimensional. Let $B \in \mathcal{B}$. Now $B =\{x\}$ for some $x \in X$. In order to show that $B$ is closed we need to show it’s complement is open. Since $B \in \tau$ it’s by definition open. Now the complement of open set is closed so $B^c=X \setminus B \subset X$. So $B^c$ is closed in $X$ and thus $X$ is zero-dimensional

Is the reasoning here correct?

Answer (score 1):

It's correct but you do not need a special base at all: all open sets are closed too. So just the base equal to the whole topology will do just as well and the proof is shortened.